# Adjoint of Differential operators

Tags: differential-geometry, calculus-of-variations, adjoint-operators

So I am working through Peter Olver's book Applications of Lie Groups to Differential equations and there is this example on page 329 that I cannot seem to figure out.

[image]

[image]

In the first highlighted part, from the formula provided I do not see how there is that extra $-u_x$ term since the formula does not require you to apply $D_x$ to $u$.

The last two highlighted parts make sense to me based on the formula that the adjoint of $D_x^2 +u $ is $(-D_x)^2 + u$ but then for the second one if I apply the same logic as the very first highlighted example I get $(-D_x)^3 - 2(D_x)\cdot u +u_x = -D_x^3 -2u_xD_x - 2u_x +u_x = -D_x^3 -2uD_x - u_x$ but again I don't understand where the extra term is coming from when the formula is simply a multiplication, so I must be interpreting this wrong could somebody please clear this up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the differential operator $(-D_x)\cdot u$ acts on a function $f$ as follows

$$((-D_x)\cdot u)(f) = -D_x(uf) = -u_xf - uf_x = (-u_x - uD_x)(f).$$

That is, as differential operators $(-D_x)\cdot u = -u_x - uD_x$ which is why the two expressions for $\mathscr{D}^*$ are equal.

Comment: I see thank you for clearing that up. So just to be clear from that you're saying if the adjoint operator $D_x^2 - uD_x -u_x$ was applied to a functional $L$ I would get $D_x^2(L) -uD_x(L) -u_x \cdot L$, where in the last term is multiplication and the first two terms are the differential operator applied to $L$.

Comment: Yes. It's only when $u$ appears after $D_x$ that you can expand it as in my answer.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up!!